# Create my own controls (play, pause, mute, seek) for JW-Player

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jwplayer6

I'm using JW-player in my web (written using AngularJs and Twitter Bootstrap) .

I want to create my own panel which controls the video, with buttons such as play/pause, mute/un-mute and the seek bar.

I saw in their [API documentation](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413089-javascript-api-reference) that I can control those video functions.

The buttons for play/pause part was easy... but how do I create the track bar that change the video position with that seek option?

I can't find an example how to use that seek option.

thanks

Comment: Easy mode, just use an `<input type="range" />`, stop updating it on _keydown_ or _mousedown_ and listen for either _keypress_ & _keyup_ or _mouseup_ to set seek position & resume updating it

Comment: Can you post a code example please?

Comment: I don't understand how to update the text that displays the current position and how to get the value when the user clicks on the track bar... please help

Comment: @TamarCohen Did you find a workaround for this problem? I'm facing the same problem with creating seekbar for JWPlayer. Documentation is so poor I can't find any advanced guides.